# Rom 5:10 Saved Luke 1:69 Salvation

Tags: greek, soteriology

What's the difference of being saved and salvation?

> Romans 5:10 (KJV) For if, when we were enemies, we were reconciled to God by
> the death of his Son, much more, being reconciled, we shall be **saved
> σῴζω  G4982** by his life.

> Luke 1:69 (KJV) And hath raised up an horn of
> **salvation σωτηρία G4991** for us in the house of his servant David;

Comment: One is a verb and the other a cognate noun.  Other than that - same meaning.  Do you have anything more specific in mind?

Comment: The difference is like in those two sentences: "Novak Djokovic won this year's Wimbledon title" and "Novak Djokovic obtained victory in finals of this year's Wimbledon". The essence does not change, for in both cases he took the same amount of +2.3 m US dollars; moreover, even if it would be written by adjective that "Novak Djokovic was victorious at the Wimbledon finals this year", his prize money would not be reduced by a penny; and the same holds with the adverb as well, "Djokovic ended up victoriously at the Wimbledon finals this year", exactly the same +2.3 m dollars, not a penny less.

Comment: @Dottard are the two frist letter the root σω is it same word different suffix?

Comment: @KevinPopov - yes - the verb and noun are "cognate" - that is, both derived from the same root word and meaning except a they are different parts of speech, ie, noun vs verb.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate the difference consider this event of having thirst quenched:

> <sup>1</sup> All the congregation of the people of Israel moved on from the wilderness of Sin by stages, according to the commandment of the Lord, and camped at Rephidim, but there was no water for the people to drink. <sup>2</sup> Therefore the people quarreled with Moses and said, “Give us water to drink.” And Moses said to them, “Why do you quarrel with me? Why do you test the LORD?” <sup>3</sup> But the people thirsted there for water, and the people grumbled against Moses and said, “Why did you bring us up out of Egypt, to kill us and our children and our livestock with thirst?” <sup>4</sup> So Moses cried to the LORD, “What shall I do with this people? They are almost ready to stone me.” <sup>5</sup> And the LORD said to Moses, “Pass on before the people, taking with you some of the elders of Israel, and take in your hand the staff with which you struck the Nile, and go. <sup>6</sup> Behold, I will stand before you there on the rock at Horeb, and you shall strike the rock, and water shall come out of it, and the people will drink.” And Moses did so, in the sight of the elders of Israel. <sup>7</sup> And he called the name of the place Massah and Meribah, because of the quarreling of the people of Israel, and because they tested the LORD by saying, “Is the LORD among us or not?” (Exodus 17 ESV)

The people had their thirst quenched when they drank water which **flowed** from the rock. In reality, it was not "water" (noun) but "flowing-water" (verb) the people drank.

The horn of salvation (Luke 1:69) is like the water which was in the rock. Even though it is present it must still be released before it becomes available. What ultimately saves is the life which is released after He is raised from the dead (Romans 5:10), if one chooses to drink.

Answer (score 0):

**Luke 1:69**

> And hath raised up an horn **of salvation** for us in the house of his
> servant David; (Luke 1:69, KJV)
>
> καὶ ἤγειρεν κέρας **σωτηρίας** ἡμῖν ἐν οἴκῳ Δαυὶδ παιδὸς αὐτοῦ (Luke
> 1:69, Greek)

The word σωτηρίας/sōtērias (KJV: of salvation, [Strong's G4991](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g4991/kjv/tr/0-1/)) is a genitive feminine singular noun in Greek.  As a genitive, it indicates a possessive case, which is why the "of" goes with it.

**Romans 5:10**

> For if, when we were enemies, we were reconciled to God by the death
> of his Son, much more, being reconciled, **we shall be saved** by his
> life. (Romans 5:10, KJV)
>
> εἰ γὰρ ἐχθροὶ ὄντες κατηλλάγημεν τῷ θεῷ διὰ τοῦ θανάτου τοῦ υἱοῦ αὐτοῦ
> πολλῷ μᾶλλον καταλλαγέντες **σωθησόμεθα** ἐν τῇ ζωῇ αὐτοῦ (Romans
> 5:10, Greek)

The word σωθησόμεθα/sōthēsometha (KJV: we shall be saved, [Strong's G4982](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/g4982/kjv/tr/0-1/)) is future-indicative passive voice verb in the first-person plural.  The future-indicative gives it the "shall", the passive voice gives it the "be" + past participle ("saved"), and the first-person plural gives it the pronoun "we".

Salvation is the gift we receive from God through the action of being saved (passive voice, because God is doing the saving, not us).